# Multiple web.config redirect rules

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-config, http-status-code-301

Im trying to do a 301 redirect as i have changed domains. Using windows server and im adding the following rule in web.config.

```
 <rule name="redirectDomain" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://replacement-cost.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?windshield-replacement-cost\.org$" />
                    </conditions>
              </rule>
```

This is working ok so far as all the pages are of the same name and file structure on the new site... except for the page that is the root of the old domain. that is now at http://replacement-cost.net/windshield-replacement-cost

is it possible to write another rule to redirect ONLY the root? while having the second rule redirect all the other pages? possibly some kind of execution ordering?

something to acheive the same result as this essentially

if ruleURLISROOT = true > goto http://replacement-cost.net/windshield-replacement-cost

else

redirect with code above

any help would be appreciated. its took me ages to just get this far! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is new rule which should be added prior to your existing rule

```
<rule name="redirect Root Domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?windshield-replacement-cost\.org$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://replacement-cost.net/windshield-replacement-cost" />
</rule>
```

This is your existing rule

```
<rule name="redirectDomain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?windshield-replacement-cost\.org$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://replacement-cost.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Perfect - You sir are a legend!